# I want display server time through Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, time, server-side

I would like to display the server time in **digital clock** through jquery and **PHP**

I already tried like this. But it didn't work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function update() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'time.php',
   timeout: 1000,
   success: function(data) {
      $("#clock1").html(data); 
      window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
   },
  });
 }
 update();
});
```

**time.php**

```
 echo time();
```

I tried like this, but this is client side only.

```
$(function(){
        $("#clock1").MyDigitClock({
            fontColor: "#83bffa" ,
            fontSize:"30px"
        });
    });
```

at the same i want to display a calender(not date) also.
For date i used this code:

```
 $(function(){
  $.datepicker.setDefaults(
    $.extend($.datepicker.regional[''])
  );
  $('#datepicker').datepicker();
  $('#datepicker2').datepicker();
});
```

This is also client side. I want display time and date separate. Please help me.

Comment: sorry actually i given like this

Comment: put your code into fiddle.com

Comment: and give me the link. we update you

Answer (score 3):

The PHP function

```
time()
```

returns the current timestamp (something like: 1379333538).
If you want to display the current time formatted, you should use

```
<?php
  echo date("H:i");
?>
```

in your PHP file.

Given your Javascript file, You need to remove the update function from the

```
$(document).ready(function(){ });
```

block. Just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  update();
});

function update() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'time.php',
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#clock1").html(data); 
      window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }
  });
}
```

For the date, you can use pretty much the same method.

Comment: Glad i could help you. Please mark as "best answer" to let others know, that this solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a json response for that.
For example:

server side:

```
$response = array('time' => date('H:i:s'), 'date' => date('Y-m-d'));
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

clien side:

```
$.getJSON('time.php', function(json) {
    $("#clock1").html(json.time);
    $("#datepicker").val(json.date); 
});
```

The json variable in function(json) will have the properties of time and date as you defined in php.